# Find center of svg shape

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

Im using `svgjs` to create my shapes. How can I find the center point of an svg shape and add an element there? In my case a red dot. I can't find any information in the documentation for a method or something that helps in this situation.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the method [`getBBox`](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/svg/methods/getBBox/) or alternatively [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). Both methods give you an object with the properties `x, y, width, height`, which you can use to calculate your center.

Since you tagged your question with `svg.js` I will also give you a solution with [`svg.js`](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js).

```
// Vanilla
node = document.getElementById('myEl').getBBox()

// with svg.js
SVG.adopt(document.getElementById('myEl')).bbox()
```

The second solution gives you back an object which has `cx` and `cy` already calculated for you.

This method can be found in the [docs](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js#bbox)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, one last question, after getting the coordinates how would i set a element on this positions?

Comment: I would use the `center` function to set the center of the element to the center of the shaoe. E.g. `circleEl.center(cx, cy)`. Thats all written in the docs. Please rtfm!

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the help, but i notice one issue, when i call SVG.adopt(this.svgElement).bbox() i notice that is giving me only 2 coordinates, and after i console.log(this.svgElement), i notice that there are 2 svg, where in each of theme, inside are 2 shapes, rect and circle, but i need to position a element in the center of the shapes inside the svg, how i would do that?