# Finding the center point coordinates of SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm looking for a solution where I can find the center of SVG line via path since I want to render the foreign object at center of SVG.

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg>
    <g
      stroke-linecap="round"
      data-linkid="36141ffc-14b0-4375-9d40-8d002ac597fc"
      stroke-opacity="0"
      stroke-width="20"
      ><svg>
        <path
          stroke-width="10"
          stroke="rgba(255,0,0,0.5)"
          d="M68.6875,52.6875 C 68.6875,102.6875
    379.6875,331.6875 379.6875,381.6875"
          tets="Fd"
        ></path>
        <foreignObject x="50" y="50" height="100" width="40">
          <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <h1>HI</h1>
          </div>
        </foreignObject>
      </svg></g
    >
    </svg>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the above code for rendering foreign object I have passed static x and y coordinates as 50. How can I calculate the center point so that HI is rendered exactly at the center of my SVG?

Comment: Your `<svg>` tag is missing a `viewBox` attribute. You also have `<g>` element outside the svg tag? And `<div>` and `<h1>` inside. Not really sure what you are trying to do with the SVG here but you are misusing the markup. I suggest you treat the svg as a singular graphic element and place it inside html markup like `div`, then you can use some normal layout and positioning techniques to get the graphics and other HTML laid out the way you want much easier.

Comment: BugsArePeopleToo can you share an example if possible, I'm not sure about this

Comment: First, please fix your SVG. SVG `<g>` elements are not valid HTML elements.  They must be inside an `<svg>` element. So your example has invalid markup.

Comment: Updated the code, you can check

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching and found this
[stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40269703/7362680)

Basically what you do is find the smallest rectangle that can fit around the svg element using the [getBBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) or [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) command which returns a rectangle element. You can then get the width and height of that element and divide both of those fields by two to get the center of that rect element.

```
mySVG = someRandomSVGElement;
surroundingRectangle = mySVG.getBoundingClientRect();

centerOfRect_X = surroundingRectangle.width/2;
centerOfRect_Y = surroundingRectangle.height/2;
```

You then add that to the x and y of the rect element to get the coordinates for the center of your `mySVG` element.

```
centerOfmySVG_X = centerOfRect_X + surroundingRectangle.x;
centerOfmySCG_Y = centerOfRect_Y + surroundingRectangle.y;
```

#### Addendum (Nov2020): with ES destructure:

```
        let { x, y, width, height } = svgElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        let cx = width / 2 + x;
        let cy = height / 2 + y;
```